# any solution for the following error that appeared after installing onchange and parallelshell node_modules?

Tags: node.js, npm

after installing the onchange and parallelshell packages for node.js by typing the following command in the node terminal

> npm install --save-dev onchange@3.3.0 parallelshell@3.0.2

and configure the package.json file as follow to be able to use the two scripts

```
    "scripts": {
"start": "npm run watch:all",
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
"lite": "lite-server",
"scss": "node-sass -o css/ css/",
"watch:scss": "onchange \"css/*.scss\" --npm run scss",
"watch:all": "parallelshell \"npm run watch:scss\" \"npm run lite\""
 }
```

and when typing **'npm start'** to run, i face the following error and cannot solve it. so help me if u can please!

The Error :

> > confusion@1.0.0 start D:\programming materials\coursera courses\web and mobile dev specialization\course 1\module 1\bootstrap exercise\assignment 1\Bootstrap4\conFusion
> >     npm run watch:all
>
> confusion@1.0.0 watch:all D:\programming materials\coursera courses\web and mobile dev specialization\course 1\module 1\bootstrap exercise\assignment 1\Bootstrap4\conFusion
>   parallelshell "npm run watch:scss" "npm run lite"
>
> child_process.js:420
>       throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('options.cwd', 'string', options.cwd);
>       ^
>
> TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "options.cwd" property must be of type string. Received type function
>       at normalizeSpawnArguments (child_process.js:420:11)
>       at spawn (child_process.js:522:38)
>       at D:\programming materials\coursera courses\web and mobile dev specialization\course 1\module 1\bootstrap exercise\assignment 1\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\parallelshell\index.js:104:17
>       at Array.forEach ()
>       at Object. (D:\programming materials\coursera courses\web and mobile dev specialization\course 1\module 1\bootstrap exercise\assignment 1\Bootstrap4\conFusion\node_modules\parallelshell\index.js:100:6)
>       at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:689:30)
>       at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:700:10)
>       at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:599:32)
>       at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:538:12)
>       at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:530:3)
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! confusion@1.0.0 watch:all: `parallelshell "npm run watch:scss" "npm run lite"`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the confusion@1.0.0 watch:all script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\MISR COMP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-07-30T15_48_55_679Z-debug.log
>   npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
>   npm ERR! errno 1
>   npm ERR! confusion@1.0.0 start: `npm run watch:all`
>   npm ERR! Exit status 1
>   npm ERR!
>   npm ERR! Failed at the confusion@1.0.0 start script.
>   npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
>   npm ERR!     C:\Users\MISR COMP\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2018-07-30T15_48_55_778Z-debug.log

Comment: It would probably be better to include the actual text of the error, rather than an image of the error.  I think most people would be hesitant to click on a random url.

Comment: done @BrianMinton

Answer (score 18):

I have had the same problem as you. We are probably doing the same course. Apparently, is a problem with version 3.0.2 of parallelshell. You just have to downgrade to version 3.0.1 and you will not have any more problems:

```
npm install --save-dev parallelshell@3.0.1
```

Comment: This solved the issue, I am doing the same course also. Hope they fix this in the next release of the package

Comment: You may need to run `npm install` after that command in case if the problem is not resolved.

Answer (score 5):

Downgrade the version of parallelshell to 3.0.1 by typing 
npm install --save-dev parallelshell@3.0.1

Then type
 npm start
And it works!!

Comment: Please make the difference to the answers by daimazon and pgarriga more obvious.

Answer (score 4):

Apparently we are doing the same course. So follow the below-mentioned way--
To install two NPM packages onchange and parallelshell use the **downgraded version of parallel shell instead of 3.0.2 us 3.0.1**:

```
npm install --save-dev onchange@3.3.0 parallelshell@3.0.1
```

Answer (score 0):

give space between -- and npm
`"watch:scss":"onchange \"css/*.scss\" -- npm run scss"`

this will end first error
for parallelshell problem
do this  copy content of index.js file from given link
https://raw.githubusercontent.com/darkguy2008/parallelshell/master/index.js
and paste it in your index.file at  `/project/node_modules/parallelshell/index.js` 
this will work.

Answer (score 0):

First Un-Install all versions of parallelshell.

> npm uninstall --save-dev parallelshell

Second Install parallelshell@3.0.1:

> npm install --save-dev parallelshell@3.0.1

Third run start:

> npm run start